# create type from pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I'm new using Scala and what I need is to create like a dynamic type based on some pattern matching function, like

```
type defType = "value1" match {
  case "value0" => typeOf[String]
  case "value1" => typeOf[Integer]
  case _ => typeOf[Double]
}

val test5 : defType = 4
```

This is just an example given that I'd to work with more complex structures, but gives the idea of what I want to do.

Comment: Pattern matching is a runtime mechanism, that's not possible. Check out Scala Macros

Answer (score 1):

I fear this is not possible, for fundamental conceptual reasons. As type rules are checked at compile time, it is not possible to derive types based on values that might be unknown until runtime.

That being said, you might be able to tackle your design problem by defining a family of [case classes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/107), each being a wrapper for a value of a specific type. By giving these classes a common base class, you can store a value of any type you wish into the same variable and extract it through type-safe pattern matching:

```
class Base
case class AString(val value: String) extends Base
case class AnInt(val value: Int) extends Base
case class ADouble(val value: Double) extends Base

val a : Base = "value1" match {
  case "value0" => AString(…)
  case "value1" => AnInt(…)
  case "value0" => ADouble(…)
}

a match {
  case AString(s) => …
  case AnInt(i) => …
  case ADouble(i) => …
  …
}
```

Comment: Someone pointed out that your case classes need to extend `Base`—but the edit was rejected before I could accept it.

Comment: @DaoWen Thanks, I forgot the `extends` clauses. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I probably don't understand what you're doing, but this seems problematic to me:

```
val test5 : defType = 4
```

The compiler needs to be able to know `defType` at *compile time*, otherwise it can't type check. Based on that, I think what you want to do is do this pattern matching at compile time by utilizing [Scala macros](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

However, I have a feeling that's not the right solution either just because this whole scenario seems very strange. If you give more detail about what the bigger picture is of what you're trying to do maybe we can suggest a better solution.